# MongoDB with Laravel 8 Authentication Failed upon php artisan migrate

Tags: mongodb, laravel-8

I Installed mongoDB in my laravel 8 project for first time, to explore mongoDB functionalities
When I run php artisan migrate I got:

MongoDB\Driver\Exception\AuthenticationException

**Authentication failed.**
at D:\xampp\htdocs\Mongo\mongonews\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Command\ListCollections.php:115

```
   my :  D:\xampp\htdocs\Mongo\mongonews\config\database.php I set the following:
 'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', 27017),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'options' => [
            // here you can pass more settings to the Mongo Driver Manager
            // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.construct.php under "Uri Options" for a list of complete parameters that you can use

            'database' => env('DB_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE', 'admin'), // required with Mongo 3+
        ],
    ],
```

And this is my .env:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=mongonews
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Thanks Geaks, appreciate your help to start my first time mongo db based laravel app
All the best.

Answer (score 1):

It was solved by removing username from **DB_USERNAME**
although It is supposed to be "root" in my case!!!!

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=27017
DB_DATABASE=news
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Hope this helps who ever faced this problem.